# Работа с SurfaceView

Tags: android

Из множества источников я сделал вывод, что наследование класса `SurfaceView` позволит рисовать на канвасе без использования метода `onDraw()`.

Однако никак не получается. Рассмотрим пример.

Класс активити не привожу - он просто устанавливает `SurfaceView` для контент вью, все стандартно.
Подкласс SurfaceView:

```
package hivasya.noteAll;

import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.*;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.os.SystemClock;

public class HVnoteView1 extends 
 SurfaceView  implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

private static final String TAG = "hivasya";    
private Canvas canvas ;     
private Bitmap space ;
private int w , h ;

public HVnoteView1(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) { //constructor
     super(context, attrs);

     getHolder().addCallback( this);
     Log.d(TAG , "construct View1 finished" );

} // end constructor

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int sw, int sh, int oldw, int oldh) {
     super.onSizeChanged(sw, sh, oldw, oldh);
     w = sw;
     h = sh;
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas c) {
     Log.d(TAG , "onDraw" );
     //c.drawBitmap(space, 0, 0, null);
}


@Override
public void surfaceChanged (SurfaceHolder hold, int format,
int width, int height) {
     Log.d(TAG , "surfaceChanged " );
     } // end surfaceChanged

@Override
public void surfaceCreated (SurfaceHolder holder) {

     Log.d(TAG , "surfaceCreated " );

     if (holder.getSurface().isValid()) Log. d(TAG, "surface valid ");
      canvas = null;
      space = Bitmap.createBitmap(w , h , Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
      space.eraseColor(Color. YELLOW);

      try {   
            if ( canvas == null) Log. d(TAG, "canvas is null " );
            canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
            if ( canvas != null) Log. d(TAG, "canvas not null " );
            synchronized(holder) {
            canvas.drawBitmap( space, 0, 0, null);
           Log. d(TAG, "synchronized" );
           SystemClock.sleep(2000);  // заморозить картинку на случай,
                                     // если она перерисовывается                           
                }
           }
            catch (Exception e) {Log. e(TAG, "lock canvas Error " + e.toString(), e);}
            finally { if ( canvas != null) holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);}

     } // end surfaceCreated

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed (SurfaceHolder hold) {
     Log.d(TAG , "surfaceDestroyed " );
     } // end surfaceDestroyed


} // end class
```

Обратите внимание на мои параноидальные логи, контролирующие каждый шаг.
Вот что выводит LogCat:

```
05-03 20:37:37.734: D/hivasya(25674): construct View1 finished
05-03 20:37:37.810: D/hivasya(25674): surfaceCreated
05-03 20:37:37.810: D/hivasya(25674): surface valid
05-03 20:37:37.842: D/hivasya(25674): canvas is null
05-03 20:37:37.846: D/hivasya(25674): canvas not null
05-03 20:37:37.861: D/hivasya(25674): synchronized
05-03 20:37:39.863: D/hivasya(25674): surfaceChanged
05-03 20:37:39.887: D/hivasya(25674): onDraw
05-03 20:37:40.011: D/hivasya(25674): onDraw
```

Как бы все работает, холдер получен, поверхность валидная, канвас получен.

Система ошибок не выдает, но не рисует.
Если в методе `onDraw` раскомментировать строку

```
 //c.drawBitmap(space, 0, 0, null);
```

рисование выполнится - экран закрасится желтым.

Как же получить канвас кроме как через параметр метода `onDraw`?
Пробовал холдер получить не через параметр, а методом `getHolder()`,
тоже бесполезно.
Спасибо за внимание.

Answer (score 4):

Поскольку ответ получен не в результате изучения документации, а методом проб и ошибок, предполагаю, что он может кому-то быть полезен.

Как выяснилось, причина все-таки в классе активити.
 Если в классе активити для установки связи с `SurfaceView` используется 
xml-разметка, например `setContentView(R.layout.main)` , то в подклассе `SurfaceView` будет вызываться метод `onDraw()`.

Преимущества: легко реализуется прокрутка и масштабирование канваса.

Недостатки: при каждом вызове `onDraw()` канвас должен перерисовываться полностью. При рисовании пальцем он вызывается при смещении на каждый пиксель. Попытка рисовать вне `onDraw()` - см. мой вопрос выше.

Примечание: В конструкторе подкласса `SurfaceView` кроме аргумента `Context` должен быть аргумент `AttributeSet`, иначе приложение сразу завершается с ошибкой.

Если в активити для установки вью используется экземпляр `SurfaceView`, например `setContentView(new MySurfaceView(this))`, метод `onDraw()` не вызывается. Получение канваса методом `lockCanvas` и последующее рисование возможно. Но здесь начинается своя головная боль.
Например, нарисованное в методе `onSurfaceCreated()` не сохраняется при последующих попытках рисовать. Документация говорит, что методу `lockCanvas`
можно передать "грязный" прямоугольник, вне которого пиксели между вызовами `lockCanvas` будут сохраняться. Но это не работает. Переданный аргументом типа `Rect` "грязный" прямоугольник будет растянут на весь экран. (Проверено методом `drawRect`, которому передан тот же прямоугольник.
Ну и, что неудивительно, с прокруткой и масштабированием все будет сложнее.

Примечание: пример выше годится для конструктора с одним аргументом типа `Context`. Здесь `AttributeSet` не обязателен. Если же этот второй аргумент присутствует, ему можно передать `NULL`.

Таким образом, метод `setContentView()` задает один из подходов к рисованию на холсте.

Проверено на планшете Lenovo с использованием IDE Eclipse.

Comment: к IDE это не имеет никакого отношения - она просто инструмент, один из многих и в каждом из них все будет точно так же